# node-ffi - printing strings that return from C++ funcs

Tags: node.js, ffi, node-ffi

I have some class MyObject

```
MyObject * m_instance;
    extern "C"
    {

        void createNew()
        {
          m_instance = new MyObject ("one", "two");
        }

        const char * getCharOne()
        {
            std::cout<< "one" <<m_instance->getFirstString().c_str()<<std::endl;
            return m_instance->m_instance->getFirstString().c_str();
        }
    }
//example.js

var ffi = require('ffi');
var libm = ffi.Library('libExample', {
  'createNew': ["void",[]],
  'getCharOne' : ['string',[]],
});

libm.createNew();
var o = libm.getCharOne();
console.log(o);
```

i get the print inside the getCharOne function, but not from the console log.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: It's `getCharOne` in C++ and `libm`, but `getCharPath` in the last lines.

Comment: just my mistake while trying a few things. Still won't work. Edited the ques